# ubuntu login loop error after partitioning

Tags: ubuntu

I recently partitioned my hard drive a few days after installing Ubuntu but when I restarted, I've been experiencing a restart loop where when I enter my login credentials, it appears to be logging in but then brings you back to the log in screen. I've tried every single method from many forums and none seem to work. I then followed one that adviced me to uninstall and later install lightdm but my computer went off as I was about to reinstall lightdm. When I finally rebooted and logged in through the terminal and tried installing lightdm, I got a 'you don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives ' error, which I've also tried all the recommended methods with no success. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Your question doesn't look like related to programming directly, so please consider using another site for this

Comment: Please check https://askubuntu.com/a/1066600/139749 solution.